# Updating instance variable through other instance variable set method

Tags: c#, oop, instance-variables

I am having a problem with my homework. I have an instance variable price that is supposed to have a get method and no set method. I have this price variable calculated and assigned through a constructor. I noticed that if you change either the width or height value to another number in `Main`, the price variable does not change. I added a `updatePrice()` method that will work if explicitly called in `Main` but would like to have it implemented automatically through the height/width set methods. I can't get it to work right now.

Explicit call to `updatePrice()` after changing width variable which works.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

class Photo
{
    private int width { get; set; }
    private int height { get; set; }
    protected double price;

    public int Width {
        get
        {
            return width;
        }
        set
        {
            updatePrice(value, height);
            width = value;
        }
    }

    public int Height {
        get
        {
            return height;
        }
        set
        {
            updatePrice(width, value);
            height = value;
        }
    }

    public Photo(int width, int height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        if (width == 8 && height == 10)
            price = 3.99;
        else if (width == 10 && height == 12)
            price = 5.99;
        else
            price = 9.99;
    }

    public virtual double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
    }

    public String ToString()
    {
        return GetType() + " with a width of " + width + " and a height of " + height +
            " with a base price of " + Price.ToString("C2");
    }

    // used to be updatePrice() w/ no parameters
    public void updatePrice(int width, int height)
    {
        if (width == 8 && height == 10)
            price = 3.99;
        else if (width == 10 && height == 12)
            price = 5.99;
        else
            price = 9.99;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Photo photo = new Photo(10, 12);

        WriteLine(photo.ToString());
        photo.height = 4;
        // updatePrice();
        WriteLine(photo.ToString());
    }
}
```

Photo with a width of 10 and a height of 12 with a base price of $5.99
    // change height to 4 
Photo with a width of 10 and a height of 4 with a base price of $5.99
    // price should be $9.99

Comment: `ToString` should be marked as `override`.

Comment: You can call `UpdatePrice` without parameters from `Width` and `Height` setters after updated the field, and you can mark it as private or protected. You can call it from constructor just after initialized fields, no need to repeat code.

Comment: Are you sure that this code compiles? You are calling the private property _height_ not the public one _Height_  Setting the _private_ member _height_ will not call the UpdatePrice method

Comment: When you step through `updatePrice` in the debugger are all of the values as expected? Is it being called at the expected points?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the price, calculate the price dynamically in the `Price` property. Like this you are sure that it always reflects the current state.

```
public virtual double Price
{
    get
    {
        if (width == 8 && height == 10) return 3.99;
        if (width == 10 && height == 12) return 5.99;
        return 9.99;
    }
}
```

---

I just made this speed test with the property as above:

```
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
    photo.Height = 4;
    double price = photo.Price;
    photo.Height = 10;
    price = photo.Price;
}
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed ms: " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Note that it calculates the price 2 million times. It takes 67 ms to execute! So it is not worth the effort to try to optimize this calculation. You are only saving a few nanoseconds. But putting the calculation in the property simplifies you code and makes it more reliable.

---

Note also that you must override the existing `ToString` method inherited from `object`.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{GetType()}: width = {width}, height = {height}, base price = {Price:C2}";
}
```

Then you can print the photo with

```
WriteLine(photo);
```

as `WriteLine` automatically uses this method now. I also used string interpolation. This is more readable than string concatenation.

Comment: It will calculate the price each time thus it is a lost of speed performance compared to setting it only when others properties have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code refactored as adviced in my comment of the question, with `updatePrice` marked protected virtual to allow polymorphism, added `.Name` in `ToString`, and I removed useless accessors of private fields:

```
class Photo
{

    private int width;
    private int height;
    protected double price;

    public int Width {
        get
        {
            return width;
        }
        set
        {
            width = value;
            updatePrice();
        }
    }

    public int Height {
        get
        {
            return height;
        }
        set
        {
            height = value;
            updatePrice();
        }
    }

    public Photo(int width, int height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        updatePrice();
    }

    public virtual double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType().Name + 
               " with a width of " + width + 
               " and a height of " + height +
               " with a base price of " + Price.ToString("C2");
    }

    protected virtual void updatePrice()
    {
        if (width == 8 && height == 10)
            price = 3.99;
        else if (width == 10 && height == 12)
            price = 5.99;
        else
            price = 9.99;
    }

}
```

So you don't need to call updatePrice from outside:

```
static void Main()
{
    Photo photo = new Photo(10, 12);

    WriteLine(photo.ToString());
    photo.height = 4;
    WriteLine(photo.ToString());
}
```

Comment: As you suggested in your comment, `updatePrice` should be `private` or `protected`.